# Eigenvalues of Jacobian around non-stationary points

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jacobian, linearization

This is a two-part question

**Part 1**

We have often done stability analysis by calculating the eigenvalues of the Jacobian of a nonlinear function around a stationary solution.

I accidentally repeated the process, but this time by calculating the Jacobian around a point that is not an equilibrium. ***Is there any meaning to the eigenvalues I obtain?***

**Part 2**

Is there also a way to obtain a general linearized operator around a non-stationary point?

$$F(\psi_x + \Delta\psi) = F(\psi_x) + \Delta\psi F'(\psi_x)$$

If $F(\psi_x) = 0$, then $F'(\psi_x)$ is the linearized operator. However, if  $F(\psi_x) \neq 0$, ***is it even possible to define a linearized operator around $\psi_x$ for an arbitrary $\Delta\psi?$***